# reveal.js: ng-repeat doesn't work with section tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, reveal.js

I am using [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js). My slides are saved in a json object. For some reason the output is only one slide with everything overwritten! Here is my code:

```
   <div class="reveal">
                <div class="slides" data-ng-controller="myControl">
                    <section data-ng-repeat="slide in allSlide">
                        {{slide}}
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my js code

```
 $scope.allSlide = [...];
```

I found in the code [here](https://github.com/robinComa/html5-presentation/blob/master/app/index.html) that reveal.js works with ng-repeat but what is the problem with mine?
Any help appreciated.
Update: Scripts are included like below at the end of html file:

```
<script src="lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/reveal.js"></script>

<script>
   Reveal.initialize({

});

 </script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that, probably because reveal.js needs to initialize at some point and that point is confused as to when angularjs has actually created the content.

Comment: thanks @PeterAshwell. here https://github.com/robinComa/html5-presentation/blob/master/app/index.html it is shown to work

Comment: Sara, could you please show how you include scripts?

Comment: Hey, your code is quite different from that code. The main part being that they have a 200ms timeout on the Reveal.initialize function. That would be why your code is not working. I will post a possible solution

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult because angularJS won't have finished rendering when reveal.js attempts to interpret the HTML into a slide show. You could try the following, which was from the link you posted where it was working:

```
<script>
   setTimeout(function() {
      Reveal.initialize({});
   }, 200);
</script>
```

Here's the relevant line from the working demo you posted:

https://github.com/robinComa/html5-presentation/blob/master/app/scripts/modules/reveal.js#L26

```
        setTimeout(function(){
            Reveal.initialize({
                controls: true,
                progress: true,
                history: true,
                center: true,

                theme: Reveal.getQueryHash().theme, // available themes are in /css/theme
                transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'default', // default/cube/page/concave/zoom/linear/fade/none
                // ... some stuff in here
            });
        }, 200);
```

Perhaps it would be a good idea to have the structure of the slides defined in advance, rather than using an ng-repeat? Perhaps lay out the sections without ng-repeat (so reveal can interpret without a timeout)  and then use ng-include to get your duplicated layouts into each section block.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm pretty new to Angular. can you please show me an example?

Comment: The timeout solution works but I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: It's not, but without using some kind of angular-wrapped version of reveal.js, which may exist, it will be an issue.